# how to use python-docx to overwrite the xml contents of a cell

Tags: python, xml, docx, python-docx

For editing `.docx` files in python, `python-docx` exposes some properties but not others. Text properties like bold, italics etc can easily be set, but cell properties like background shading and borders can't AFAIK.

What you *can* do in `python-docx` is to view the xml of the cell using the `.xml` attribute. So `cell._tc.xml` reveals that cell properties are held in a `<w:tcPr> ... </w:tcPr>` block. This can be a nested structure, for example

```xml
  <w:tcPr>
    <w:tcW w:w="1139" w:type="dxa"/>
    <w:tcBorders>
      <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="000000"/>
      <w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="000000"/>
    </w:tcBorders>
    <w:shd w:fill="FFDBB6" w:val="clear"/>
  </w:tcPr>
```

I would like to copy the exact cell properties from one cell to another cell. I've tried:

1. simply copying the xml `<w:tcPr>` block from one cell to the other. However, the `.xml` attribute is read only - `python-docx` doesn't allow setting xml directly.
2. looping through the source cell's xml structure recursively and setting those properties in the destination cell. So something on the lines of

```py
for child in source_cell._tc.get_or_add_tcPr().iterchildren():
    dest_cell._tc.get_or_add_tcPr().insert(child)
```

but that is raising `TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'CT_TcPr'`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: > "python-docx doesn't allow setting XML directly."
Well there you go, you can't. You can however change the ending of a `.docx` file to `.zip`, open it, and then edit the document XML directly. [An Informal Introduction to DOCX](https://www.toptal.com/xml/an-informal-introduction-to-docx)

Comment: Thanks @DerSchinken. Changing the cell properties is one of many manipulations I'm performing. Most of them can be done within `python-docx`, and it would be a shame to have to use a roundabout route for cell properties...

Comment: @gnoodle, But if it does not have that feature pre-built, then one would have to build it.  So it would be useful to start with the link or similar to verify if the feature exists or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function which copies the properties from one cell to another:

```py
def copy_cell_properties(source_cell, dest_cell):
    '''Copies cell properties from source cell to destination cell.

    Copies cell background shading, borders etc. in a python-docx Document.

    Args:
        source_cell (docx.table._Cell): the source cell with desired formatting
        dest_cell (docx.table._Cell): the destination cell to which to apply formatting
    '''
    # get properties from source cell
    # (tcPr = table cell properties)
    cell_properties = source_cell._tc.get_or_add_tcPr()
    
    # remove any table cell properties from destination cell
    # (otherwise, we end up with two <w:tcPr> ... </w:tcPr> blocks)
    dest_cell._tc.remove(dest_cell._tc.get_or_add_tcPr())

    # make a shallow copy of the source cell properties
    # (otherwise, properties get *moved* from source to destination)
    cell_properties = copy.copy(cell_properties)

    # append the copy of properties from the source cell, to the destination cell
    dest_cell._tc.append(cell_properties)
```

There is a related discussion here - https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/205